# Vlan and bridge

Tags: linux, bridge, vlan

Is it possible to drop Vlan tagged packets received on a non-vlan interface(enslaved in a bridge) in Linux, by virtue of some configuration? Can it be done using bridge vlan ingress filter in Linux?
For example - eth0 is part of br0. A tagged packet is received on eth0 and passed up the Linux stack by the ethernet driver.

Comment: Are you using VLAN tagged frames on other interfaces beside *eth0*, or do you just want to drop *any* VLAN tagged packet *anywhere*? If you're using some, could you give a more complete description (what VLANs on what interfaces/bridge ports etc.), so I could adapt an answer?